# Use & inside the content of a pseudo-element

Tags: sass

Using SCSS, I am setting the content of a ::before using a loop:

```
@each $element in del, choice, subst, abbr {
  #{$element}::before {content: "#{$element}";
}
```

Can that be done using & instead of a loop, something like:

```
del, choice, subst, abbr {
   &::before {content: "#{&} }
}
```

?

Comment: So you want your content property to say "del", "choice" etc?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.